# How to combine multiple columns data into one in spark sql or pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

the table contains columns cat, ID, V1 and V2.

input

Cat ID  V1 V2

A   1  AA       AA

A   1   NULL        BB

C   3   AA NULL

C   3       NULL    BB

expected output format.

output
Cat ID  V
A   1       AA
A   1      AA
A   1      BB
C   3       AA
C   3      BB
can this be done without union all?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce for this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, col

df.withColumn("V", coalesce(col("V1"), col("V2")))
```

Comment: This code would not create a new record in output.

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question then.